# how to share multiple photos on facebook through intent not through the facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, share, photo

Here is my code and using this code there is no Facebook option coming in the share dialogue box.

```
Intent  sendIntentmultiple = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

sendIntentmultiple.setType("image/jpeg");
sendIntentmultiple.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "“Just another nice click! Check it out now.”");
sendIntentmultiple.setType("text/plain");
System.out.println("shareimage_list"+shareimage_list);
//sendIntentmultiple.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, shareimage_list);
sendIntentmultiple.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, shareimage_list);
startActivity(sendIntentmultiple);
```